# Unable to resolve the source file for in Custom Offline Payment method in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment

I have created one **offline payment method** which will be visible to our specific customer group, all this is working fine in localhost but after uploading code in server i am getting following error at checkout page:

> /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/StaticResource.php(97):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile() #1
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258):
>   Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch() #2
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/pub/static.php(13):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource))#3 {main}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error with file type- I was trying with phtml file in but knockout js binds HTML files.
After reading few blogs i got this solution:

The html binding causes the associated DOM element to display the HTML specified by your parameter.

Typically this is useful when values in your view model are actually strings of HTML markup that you want to render.
 for more details- http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html